Определение переменной с именем undefined в js
что означает данная запись?
undefined = 1

В плане что тут происходит?
Я имею ввиду что если я напишу
let undefined = 1
console.log(undefined)

Вывод
1

А если
undefined = 1
console.log(undefined)

Вывод
undefined

Вопрос возник пока читал про null и undefined

undefined - зарезервированное слово и тип данных. Не используйте зарезервированные слова, в качестве переменных

@SwaD в том-то и проблема, что оно не зарезервированное, хотя должно бы быть. Вот тут есть ответ на английском  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173833/1016033

В общем, это такой баг дизайна языка, который уже невозможно исправить.

undefined это свойство, определённое в окружении (по умолчанию глобальная проперти в рантайме).
С помощью let и var вы создаёте новую переменную с таким же именем в вашей области видимости. Однако нельзя изменить значение глобальной переменной undefined.
В то же время такие фокусы с null не пройдут, потому что это ключевое слово языка.
